# <br> become &lt;br&gt; when taken from mongodb meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, meteor

I have a little problem here. my 
 tag became <br> instead when I tried to set the text of label from mongodb.

//my meteor methods

```
Meteor.methods({
  addEventDetails : function(title, details) {
    details=details.replace('\n', "<br>");
    eventDetails.insert({'title': title, 'details': details});
  } 
});
```

//my template function

```
Template.detailsboard.evt = function(){
    return eventDetails.findOne({});
  }
```

//my template

```
<template name="detailsboard">
    <div class="block">
        <div class="navbar navbar-inner block-header">

            <div class="pull-left"><i class="icon-bookmark"></i><span class="block-header-title">Event Details</span></div>
            <div class="pull-right searchbar"></div>
            <!-- <div class="pull-right"><span class="badge badge-warning">View More</span></div> -->
        </div>
        <!-- /block header-->
        <!-- block content -->
        <div class="block-content-details collapse in">
            <ol class="stream-items" id="stream-items-id">
                <a class="logo-details" href="/"></a>
                <div class="row-fluid" style="padding:10%">
                    <div class="span12">
                    <label class="text-inverse details-title">{{evt.title}}</label>
                    **//problem here**
                    <p class="text-inverse details-content">this.html({{evt.details}})</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </ol>
        </div>
        <!-- /block content -->
    </div>
    <!-- block header -->
</template>
```

Comment: triple mustache `{{{evt.details}}}`

Comment: @Prinzhorn I mustache you to post that as an answer so OPs question can have a proper chosen solution.

Comment: Done. I was on a rush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a triple mustache `{{{evt.details}}}`, because by default Handlebars (or originally Mustache) escapes HTML.